# grails namedQueries how to use OR

Tags: grails, named-query

Essentially I have 3 fields I want to check for:

```
class Book {
   String title
   String ISBN
   String type
}
```

I am trying to use named queries to do a case insensitive search of each of those 3 fields based on a single search string. Here is what I currently have:

```
    static namedQueries = {

        search { String searchString ->
        ilike("title", searchString) 
        or {
           ilike("ISBN", searchString)
        }
        or { 
           ilike("type", searchString)
        }
    }
```

I don't get any exceptions or anything, however, it simply returns no results when there should be some. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I updated to doelleri's example and it is working now. Here is the last portion of the query:

```
from book this_ where (lower(this_.title) like ? or lower(this_.isbn) like ? or lower(this_.type) like ?)
```

I also did a breakpoint inside the named query to determine if the string was getting passed in, and it was.

Comment: Can you add logSql = true in your datasource config and check the query that hibernate generate?

Comment: Alright - I'm doing that now - will post results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the correct syntax is

```
static namedQueries = {
    search { String searchString ->
        or {
            ilike("title", searchString)
            ilike("ISBN", searchString)
            ilike("type", searchString)
        }
    }
}
```